# Teamcity - Build Number - Pass into ant script

Tags: java, ant, teamcity, parameters, numbers

I want to pass the build number from Teamcity into an ant script as a parameter. Does anyone know the exact syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The build number is passed as a system property at build time. You can see the predefined properties available [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Predefined+Properties). In this case you would reference it in ant as a property like so:

```
 ${build.number}
```

Comment: Yes, that's how we do it with nant.

Comment: My TeamCity runs a .bat (batch file). How can it get the build number?

Comment: @koumides, I would expect %build.number% would work. Never tried it, though.